# Cannot read property of undefined error when trying to save form element to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting this error when I submit the form:

> Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Thanks in advance guys/gals :)

```
////// NODE CODE //////
var MyUser = mongoose.model( 'users' , { name: String } );

app.post( '/user' , function ( req, res ) {
    var User = new MyUser( {
        name: req.body.firstName
    })
    .save( function ( err, doc ) {
        err ? res.send( err ) : res.redirect( '/' );
    });  
});


/////// MARKUP /////
<form method="POST" action="/user">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" /> 
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you use this middleware https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser to parse the body ?

Comment: Are you sure? Like this `app.use( bodyParser());`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not defining a good schema

```
var MyUser = mongoose.model( 'users' , { name: String } );
```

You are just passing a simple object as second parameter which needs to be a
`Schema` instance.

So it will something like

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String 
});
var MyUser = mongoose.model( 'users' , userSchema );
```

This works too:

```
var MyUser = mongoose.model( 'users' , new mongoose.Schema({name: String}));
```

[Here are some documentation on how to define a mongoose model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/model-definition.html)